# How to abort XMLHttpRequest if taking a lot of time to load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest

I have recently started using XMLHttpRequest. Is there a way to abort the request if a request is taking too much time to give a response? and Another question when I make a request why am I not able to do console.log in XMLHttpRequest.onprogress?

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if(this.readyState === 4)
           resolve(something)
}
xhr.onprogress = function () {
   console.log("loading..") // not printing
}

 xhr.open('GET', url);
//headers
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To abort simply use `xhr.abort()` method and it will cancel your request. Also as you don't want it to cancel unless it's working so you can set a time limit within which abort will be executed if the response is not retrieved.

Also take a variable `isReceived` and set it to false. Now if the response is received it will be set to true and the abort() method won't be executed. else if it is not received within the desired time, it will remain false and will be aborted

```
let isReceived = false;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if(this.readyState === 4)
           isReceived = true;
           resolve(something)
}
xhr.onprogress = function () {
   console.log("loading..") // not printing
   setTimeout(function(){  
     if(!isReceived){
     xhr.abort(); 
    }
   }, 2000);
}

 xhr.open('GET', url);
//headers
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Where should I position this statement, in the above code?

Comment: Is it worth cancelling the timeout if the AJAX op is successful? I suppose it can't be aborted if it has finished, but it still feels a bit dirty to call `abort()` regardless of the outcome.